# What's a good tool to allow for detection and tracing of infrequent deadlocks on SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server-2008

We have an CRM 4 server which is being used in production with many SSIS jobs syncing data in it from external sources.  We also have a fairly large number of async workflows & sync plugins that run on our entities.  Every now and then we will get deadlocks even though we've put the read snapshot committed on in our SQL 2008.  Are there any tools we could point at our sql server and when deadlocks occur would give us as much information as possible about that processes and the query text those processing are running which caused the deadlocks?

Comment: Why not just have a startup stored procedure that sets up a trace that records the deadlock graph event?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have used SQL Profiler to do this. Configure it with the **Deadlock graph** and **Lock: Deadlock** events (under "Locks"), along with (my recommended set) columns SPID, HostName, ApplicationName, LoginName, DatabaseName, ObjectID, ObjectID2, OwnerId, Type, Mode, StartTime, EndTime, Duration, and (most importantly) TextData. Start it up, and let it run. If and when deadlocks occur, both events track useful information, but one of them (probably Deadlock graph) traps and records a ton of useful information as XML in the Text column. When the row (event) is selected in the Profiler GUI it will display a graphic showing kinda useful information... but what you do is, extract the XML from the TextData column (cut and paste works fine) and view it in your preferred XML editor to see just about anything you could ever possibly want to know about what caused that $*%& deadlock.

Of course, you have to have SQL Profiler running continuosly on someone's box to do this. If you have to wait hours or days for a deadlock to happen, you'll want to set up and mangae a trace on the server itself. (Complex subject, read up on "sp_trace_create" in Books Online for details. SQL Profiler is really just a GUI sitting on top of Trace calls.) Fire them up by hand, or as @Chris.w.mclean suggests, you could configure an autorun procedure to start it up if you want it to always be running (though extracting data from an always running trace is yet another tricky issue). I've also set up a one-time-run SLQ Agent job to start traces when I want them to start (generally when I'm asleep).